# MySQL / MariaDB add column documentation

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Can I add documentation to a table that I could query from within the database? It would be great to understand properties when you come back to a table after a long time.

Comment: MySQL and MariaDB both supports making comments on tables or columns for that matter..

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and MariaDB do have a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` feature, but it will just show the basic DDL which would generate the table which exists in your database.  It won't show any comments which might have been present in the actual `CREATE` statement you ran when you created the table.  One possible solution here would be to just maintain your `CREATE` scripts in your application code base, including any comments you want.  You could version the scripts using a tool like Liquibase.  Then, when you want to see the comments, just view the scripts.

Comment: *" It won't show any comments which might have been present in the actual CREATE statement you ran when you created the table. "* Yes it does https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cG8Zue33x1w7s4Ffw8xUt/0

Comment: @RaymondNijland That's good to know, but I was referring to `--comments` which a developer might have peppered throughout the script.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I think it would be a great feature to do something like `show docs table  XYZ` . Just like docstrings in any language, but now persistent at runtime (it's a db, right :D )

Comment: @RaymondNijland Your link is not really clear to me. If you think this is the solution to my question, please post it as an answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `COMMENT` option on columns, tables, and certain other constructs.  Example:

```
mysql> create table with_comments (x int comment "column comment" 
        ) comment "table comment";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> show create table with_comments\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: with_comments
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `with_comments` (
  `x` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'column comment'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci COMMENT='table comment'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Caveat:  Such comments are rather limited in length.

If you want to supply paragraphs of documentation, you would need some ad hoc mechanism, such as a db with a table with a `TEXT` column for stuff.